# Parse a String to a generic Comparable

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Filter<T> where T : IComparable<T> {

  public static Boolean TryParse(String[] values, out List<T> result) {      

  }

}
```

I need to check if all values are convertible to T. If yes then return the converted values in "result". But if at least one is not convertible I would like to return false and result as null.

I would use Int32 parse, Boolean parse, ... But in this case I am not sure of the type T. I just know it is comparable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you use `IConvertable<T>`?

Comment: Good question. I'm afraid that the answer will be "use a large switch block with all supported data types", but I'll gladly be proven wrong. Of course, if you don't object to the idea of using exceptions for control flow, using `Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T))` and an exception handler would work.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: T will only be Int, Boolean, Datetime and Double so I think I can use convertible, right?

Comment: @Heinzi: I do not want to throw an exception if it not convertible

Comment: if it is `IConvertable` then you can contrain it that way.

Comment: @Heinzi I would note that `ChangeType` uses the equivalent of a `switch` statement to redirect to the right `IConvertible.ToXXX` overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this, which works pretty well most of the time:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue) 
    ? default(T)
    : (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString(stringValue);
```

The type descriptor also offers a `CanConvertFrom` method, which allows you to check in advance whether your type is convertible.

The full solution to your problem would be this:

```
public static Boolean TryParse(String[] values, out List<T> result) 
{      
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)); // Store these in a concurrent dictionary if you want to be more efficient
    if (!converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    result = values.Select(value => (T)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(value)).ToList();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You use `typeof(T)` in both `GetConverter` and `CanConvert`. Shouldn't one of them be `typeof(String)` instead?

Comment: @Rob Lyndon I do not understand where are you checking if the value in the string can be convertible to type T.

Comment: Pardon me -- I'd created the converter twice.  Corrected now.

Comment: It's the line `if (!converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(T)))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter) (at least for those types that have an own `TypeConverter`, which seems to be the case for most standard types):

```
public class Filter<T> where T : IComparable<T> 
{
    public static Boolean TryParse(String[] values, out List<T> result)     
    {
        result = null;

        try
        {
            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            result = values.Select(v => converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(v)).ToList();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

For your custom types you would need to implement your own `TypeConverter`s. See [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ayybcxe5(v=vs.120)) on how to do that.

Comment: I would like to not use Try Catch in this.

Comment: @MiguelMoura I understand that, but unfortunatly there is no `TryConvert` in this `TypeConverter` and it throws if the `string` cannot be parsed. But this will only happen once per call, so the performance impact should not be so big.

Comment: [Using catch without a specific exception type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx), and [using exceptions for control flow](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why) are not high on the best practices list...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I mostly agree with those guidelines, but there *guidelines* though - not rules. And I did not implement this `TypeConverter` without a not-throwing method. I just tried it with `int` and was horrified to see that it's throwing a base `Exception` - not even a derived type. ...and I don't use it for control flow here.